# MongoDB cant access document above at specific skip

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, large-data

I have a MongoDB instance in a cloud on AWS EC2 t2.micro (30GB storage, 1GB ram) running in Docker and in that database I have a single collection which stores 411 thousand documents, an this takes ~700MB disk space.

[image: robomongo]

On my local computer, if I run this in `mongo` shell:

```
db.my_collection.find().skip(200000).limit(1)
```

then I get the correct results, but if I run this

```
db.my_collection.find().skip(220000).limit(1)
```

then MongoDB shuts down. Why? What should I do, to access these data?

Comment: I'd recommend looking into log file and see what does it says.

Comment: In the logs, I see nothing. At least when I do `docker logs -f mongodb`. I think this is the only place of the logs.

Comment: Well, other reason I can think of is memory. As you mentioned your system as 1GB ram, which is not optimal. If increasing in RAM is not possible for you, I'd suggest increase or add more swap space.

Comment: Is there a reason to skip that many document? It is more efficient and performant to [query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/) the document using the `_id` instead.

Comment: Yeah, I want to access these documents. I can't show them in a simple paged list. I will try to increase swap space.

Comment: I added swap and now it is working. If you post your tip as an answer, I am willing to accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your system doesn't have enough RAM to fulfill mongodb demand. When a Linux system is critically low in memory, kernel starts killing processes to avoid system crash itself.

I believe, this is what happening in your case too. Mongodb is not even getting chance to write a log. I'd recommend to increase RAM or if it's not feasible, add more swap space. This will prevent system crash but mongodb will keep working though very very slow.

Please visit these excellent resources on Linux and it's behavior.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136291/will-linux-start-killing-my-processes-without-asking-me-if-memory-gets-short

https://serverfault.com/questions/480266/how-to-know-if-the-server-runs-out-of-ram-before-crashing-down